# module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'xfeatures'

Tags: python, opencv

experiencing,  AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'xfeatures'

updated  the version of openCV,  installed/updated  opencv-contrib-python, but the error remains the same.

sift = cv2.xfeatures.SIFT_create()

Comment: cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create() ?

Comment: it solves the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem when I was doing my master project. 
Try Python version=3.6 and then install the latest version of OpenCV.

Here is the solution:

```
pip install opencv
# must install the extra package below
pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.3.0.10
```

Hope it works for you, good luck!